# com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Request is missing required authentication credential

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am using google app engine and google datastore.
I am using the google library

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore
```

My sample code is:

```
Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
Key taskKey = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind(entityName).newKey(id);
//populate some fields....
datastore.put(task);
```

I am using spring-boot and jetty as a container.

On local, it is working properly and the data updated in the google datastore.

The issue is when im deploying the app to the google-app-engine, im getting the Below exception when i get to datastore.put method.

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:129)
com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.commit(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:155)
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreImpl$4.call(DatastoreImpl.java:485)
```

Note: in both, on local environment and google-app-engine, i defined the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS that point to json file with all required credentials generated by google API.

Comment: As a work around, i used the library com.google.appengine.api.datastore instead of com.google.cloud.datastore and the problem solved. still not sure what is the issue with com.google.cloud.datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation for [connecting to Datastore from App Engine in Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine), there are several options available, so you can either go with **Objectify** (third party library), **Datastore API** or **Datastore Client Library**.

With the usage of Client Libraries, you must know that they make use of the [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application), in such a way that, as documented, if the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, ADC uses the default service account that App Engine provides for applications running over that service. So in your case, I think you should not define the environment variable, so that App Engine uses its default Service Account.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `<url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>` with Java8 and Objectify 6 you will have to switch into `native` and enable billing.

I was hit by this issue recently and spend a lot of time on fixing the problem, more info can be found [here](https://www.vvzixun.com/index.php/code/5384c3bcfd81e1a7b0121d220b89e61a)

Answer (score 0):

if you still struggling with `com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.` you can set credentials explicitly, like it is shown in the example below:

```
            Resource credentialsCyberpower = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:yourservice-datastore-access.json");


            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsCyberpower.getInputStream())
                  .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
            DatastoreOptions options =
                    DatastoreOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("XXXXXX").setCredentials(credentials).build();
            Datastore datastore = options.getService();
            ObjectifyService.init(new ObjectifyFactory(datastore));
```

generate `yourservice-datastore-access.json` in IAM service accounts. working with Objectify 6.0.5